# rotating btn increment 45 degrees not working

Tags: jquery

I have a script I'm using to rotate a button 45 degrees every time it's clicked.  I have a list of articles with a plus sign next to them and when you click it, it rotates 45 degrees into an X and toggles open a paragraph, clicking it again rotates 45 degrees forward again into a plus and toggles the paragraph closed.  I have many of these buttons so I was trying to write something that could apply to all of them.  More then one of them can be opened at once, and I'm running into a problem where when one is opened and another one is clicked, the second one rotates 90 degrees instead of 45 and I'm not 100 percent sure why but I think it has to do with how the variable is set up, but again I'm not sure and I'm also not sure how to modify it if it is actually the problem.  My code is posted below and I have a demo of the set up here http://jsbin.com/atinap/16/edit

Here is my JS:

```
$(".info_btn").css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out");

var info_btn_DEG = 0;

$(".info_btn").toggle(function() {
$(this).closest('.article_wrapper').find('.description').slideDown("250");
info_btn_DEG += 45;
$(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + info_btn_DEG + "deg)");
$(this).fadeTo("200", 0.65);
}, function() {

$(this).closest('.article_wrapper').find('.description').slideUp("200");
info_btn_DEG += 45;
$(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + info_btn_DEG + "deg)");
$(this).fadeTo("250", 0.3);
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [45 degree rotation increment on click w/out using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289849/45-degree-rotation-increment-on-click-w-out-using-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate an angle with each element, not have one global angle for all elements - use .data():

```
function increaseAngle(elem) {
var oldAngle = $(elem).data('angle');
var newAngle = oldAngle + 45;
$(elem)
    .css("-webkit-transform", "rotateZ(" + newAngle + "deg)")
    .data('angle', newAngle);
}

$(".info_btn")
.css("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.25s ease-in-out")
.data('angle', 0);
.toggle(function() {
    $(this).closest('.article_wrapper').find('.description').slideDown(250);
    increaseAngle(this);
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 0.65);
}, function() {
    $(this).closest('.article_wrapper').find('.description').slideUp(200);
    increaseAngle(this);
    $(this).fadeTo(250, 0.3);
});
```